# Identifying font type

Tags: fonts, logo, font-identification

I tried searching on WhatTheFont Site and asked in the forum to identify the font.
Here is the Logo:

[image: MSB]

The font type of the "MSB" 3D text needs to be identified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks quite much like [Gill Sans Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/gill-sans/bold/) where `S` has been appended with rectangles to achieve flatter top and bottom lines.

Comment: Agreed.   The clue was the mix of serif and sans-serif letters